# Facebook post request sometimes get me the post and sometimes not (very strange)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

i'm using the javascript sdk and I'm trying to get public posts from a facebook account.
This is the code I use for setting up ajax and getting the access token (I use my app secret in the request because the program runs just on my computer and there is no client exposed to it).

```
<head>
    <title>Hopfully Facebook</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">//connect to ajax</script> 
</head>
<body>
<script>
var token;
$.ajax({url: "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?\client_id=APPID&client_secret=APPSECRET&grant_type=client_credentials",
     success: function(result){
        token = result.access_token; //in this var the access_token is stored
}); // end of the access_token request
</script>
```

This is the setting of the javascript sdk and the request of the first post's mesasge.

```
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'APPID',
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.9'
});  //setting up the javascript sdk

var firstPostId;

FB.api(
      ('/AviBitterOfficial/posts?access_token='+token),
      'GET',
      { "limit" : "1"},
      function(response) {
console.log(response);
firstPostId = JSON.stringify(response.data[0].id);
firstPostId = firstPostId.substring(1, firstPostId.length -1);

    FB.api(                                     // the second call is in the first call's call back in order to bypass the async problem 
    ('/'+ firstPostId+'?access_token='+token),  // that the second call has initialized before the first call back
    'GET',
    {"fields":"message"},
        function(response) {
            alert(response.message);
        }
    );
      }
);

};

      (function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

Every time I run the program, it generates the same key, but the problem with it is a bit strange. when I use the token to make an api call to get a post's text, it sometimes make the call and give me the text, but sometimes it gives me this error "Invalid OAuth access token." code 109.
This is weird because both in the times that the api call successes and both in the times it gives me the error, the token is the same and everything else is the same as well.
Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I guess sometimes the AJAX call to get the token is faster than loading the JS SDK, you need to do those things in a sequence. Right now you do it at the same time, asynchronously.

I am not sure why you do that AJAX call anyway (and why you are using jQuery for a simple AJAX call, but that´s another story), if you want to get an APP Token you can just use the App ID and App Secret with a pipe sign: `App-ID|App-Secret` - you should only do that server side, of course. But you should move most of your code to the server anyway, to include some caching if a lot of users hit your page.

Comment: @luschm   I'm very new to programming in the net, so I might be doing somethings that I shoudn't, but i just need to get some posts and their info and i don't think I'll have to do anything like this in the near future. I think you are roght about the problem happening because the api is asynchronous, and do you know anyway to control the order of the calls i make?

Comment: put the ajax call in the fbAsyncInit callback function, and do the rest in the success callback.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked :) in the rest of my code i have a loop that make a request at every round of it, but because of the asynchronousity of the api, the requests are done in the wrong order' do you know a way to fix that? @luschn

Comment: i see no loop in your question, but those things can usually be done with async/await: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
...or old school with a recursive function.